# c# lambda expression with customString for determinate Id or Name

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, lambda, filter

I try a lambda expression with a custom string.

I want something like that:

```
List<File> result = new List<File>();
string typeFilter = filter.Split('=',' ')[1];
string fileFilter = filter.Split('\'')[1];

result = ctx.Files.ToList();
List<File> res = (List<File>)result.FindAll(x => (x.typeFilter == fileFilter));

return res;

where typeFilter = Id or Name ...
and fileFilter = Id value or Name value ...
```

But I can't because File not content a definition for `typeFilter`.
Someone can help for add in my expression a `customString = Id or Name or Size` ... or just can I get something like that?

If I really can't, I need to use Oracle filter in my URI 
`(/Suppliers?$filter=Address/City eq 'Redmond')` but I don't know how.

This solved:

```
FindAll(x => (x.Name == fileFilter) || (x.Id == fileFilter) || ...);
```

but the large request is really bad for performance.

Comment: Just `FindAll(x => (x == fileNameFilter))`? Can you provide a complete example? What is ctx where does filter come from?

Comment: Sure, sorry             using (var ctx = ManageEfContext.GetContext()) ctx is the actual context. And i can't use this FindAll(x => (x == fileNameFilter)) because (cannot convert a File type to a string).

Comment: And i need x.Name == "Remond" for example but i need x.Id == "1" too.Not x == "Remond" this return 0.